# Why when I upload an Api permission via Powershell to AzureAd I get only the Id?

Tags: azure, powershell, api, permissions, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to upload some api permission to my app registration in Azure, but I don't get why for some the process work and for others no. [image: Screen of the result]

```
$svcGraph = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }

$Graph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$Graph.ResourceAppId = $svcGraph.AppId

$delPermission1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214","Scope"

$delPermission2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d","Scope"

$Graph.ResourceAccess = $delPermission1, $delPermission2

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $MyAppObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess $Graph
```

User.read (delPermission2) work, but User.Read.All (delPermission1) don't, and I don't understand why.

I tried multiple permission, but just User.read worked, here are the id and value:

741f803b-c850-494e-b5df-cde7c675a1ca     User.ReadWrite.All

83cded22-8297-4ff6-a7fa-e97e9545a259     Presence.ReadWrite.All

810c84a8-4a9e-49e6-bf7d-12d183f40d01     Mail.Read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the ID's you are using for **User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Presence.ReadWrite.All** and  **Mail.Read** permissions are ***incorrect***.

To find the correct ID's of those delegated permissions, make use of below cmdlet:

```
 $svcGraph.Oauth2Permissions | FT ID, Value, UserConsentDisplayName
```

From that, note down the correct ID's of all those permissions:

**`User.Read.All`**    -   ***a154be20-db9c-4678-8ab7-66f6cc099a59***

**`User.ReadWrite.All`**  -  ***204e0828-b5ca-4ad8-b9f3-f32a958e7cc4***

**`Presence.Read.All`** - ***9c7a330d-35b3-4aa1-963d-cb2b9f927841***

**`Presence.ReadWrite`**   -  ***8d3c54a7-cf58-4773-bf81-c0cd6ad522bb***

**`Mail.Read`** - ***570282fd-fa5c-430d-a7fd-fc8dc98a9dca***

The ID that you are using for **User.Read** is correct. That's why it worked.

**`User.Read`** - ***e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d***

Make sure you have the role of Administrator and use the correct ID's by modifying the values.

For more reference, please find below **reference** if it is helpful.

[How to assign Permissions to Azure AD App by using PowerShell? – Beyond the Horizon… (rajanieshkaushikk.com)](https://rajanieshkaushikk.com/2019/07/31/how-to-assign-permissions-to-azure-ad-app-by-using-powershell/)